# CSS list to expand to the same height as content in div

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have a div that has two divs that float left/right respectively. The right div contains a lot of text, and the left div has 3 images.

I am trying to make it so that the three images are distributed with one at the top, middle, and bottom of text, so that if more text were added then the images would move to 'correctly fill the space'

I have a 'ul' inside the left and if I set the `height:200px;` property it displays correctly, but I can't get it to match the height of the other div dynamically! I've tried using % and tried the +1000 -1000 padding/margin hack but that doesn't seem to do have the desired effect, so I must be barking up the wrong tree. (I have searched all morning on this and I can make the div work but not the ul height to match the div!).

JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/b98Rx/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="articleBody">
<div id="articleMainText">
    <p>This is some text that should overflow to the some space below here</p>
</div>
<div id="articleMainImages">
    <ul id="articleMainImagesUL">
      <li><span><img src="http://phrogz.net/tmp/gkhead.jpg"></span></li>
      <li><span><img src="http://phrogz.net/tmp/gkhead.jpg"></span></li>
      <li><span><img src="http://phrogz.net/tmp/gkhead.jpg"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: (In fiddle)

Example as an image:

[image]

Sorry for the MSPaint but I hope it shows what I'm trying to do!

I am open to other suggestions and I don't have to use a ul/li. Ideally to be compatible with as much as possible! I might make this into a 2 column table and make three seperate divs for each image to align top, middle, and bottom! Would this work?

**EDIT:**
Solved it myself, see this fiddle for how I did it! http://jsfiddle.net/B63Yy/

Comment: try putting `#articleMainImages { height: inherit; }` in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What *might* work is having nested divs, and having the images as backgrounds, attached to top, middle and bottom - though they would not print to paper. Of if you are targetting browsers that support multiple background css then use that.

This would not work if the text was too short as the images would start to overlap - unless you enforce a min-height.

Otherwise I think you are looking at javascript to do this.

Anyone know better?

Update: this kinda works ... needs polishing though.

```
<div id="articleBody">
    <div id="articleMainText">
        <div id="a"><div id="b"><div id="c">
        <p>This is some text that should overflow to the some space below here. This is some text that should overflow to the some space below here. This is some text that should overflow to the some space below here. This is some text that should overflow to the some space below here</p>
            </div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>

#articleBody { /* Body of article */
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#ecd;
}
#articleMainText { /* Main text DIV */
    width:10em;
    margin-right:32px;
    padding-left:32px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
#a, #b, #c {
    background-image: url("http://phrogz.net/tmp/gkhead.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:20px 20px;
}

#a{background-position: left top}
#b{background-position: left center}
#c{background-position: left bottom}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because the nested DIVs seems to be the best bet! Another entire day of searching and trying tables and other divs has got me nowhere, but your example (with some polishing) does the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your fiddle to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/b98Rx/7/

what I changed was:

```
#articleMainImages img {
    bottom:0;position:absolute;
}

#articleMainImagesUL li {
    height:33%;
    position:relative
}
```

and deleted the table-cell props where you had them.